# Error in insertion in binary search tree

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

My code is insert elements in binary search tree but after inserting first element the program is stop running and is not executing further

```
 typedef struct BST
 {
   int info;
   struct BST * left;
   struct BST *right;
 }
bst;
```

//Global root variable

```
bst *root;
```

//Insert function

```
void insert(int x) //x is the elemnent to be inserted
{
bst *ptr,*ptr1;
ptr=(bst*)malloc(sizeof(bst));
if(root==NULL) //checking whether the tree is empty or not
  {
  ptr->left=ptr->right=NULL;
  root=ptr;
  }
else
  {
  ptr1=root;
while(ptr1!=NULL)
  {
  if(x>ptr1->info)   //traversing to right if element is greater than  element present
    ptr1=ptr1->right;
  else
    ptr1=ptr1->left; //traversing to left if element is present than the the element
  }
 }
if(x>ptr1->info)
 {
  ptr1->right=ptr;
  ptr->info=x;
 }
else
 {
  ptr1->left=ptr;
  ptr->info=x;
 }
}
```

//show function using preorder traversal

```
void preorder(bst *root)
{
 bst *ptr=root;
 printf("%d",ptr->info);
 preorder(ptr->left);
 preorder(ptr->right);
}

int main()
{
int n,x,i;
puts("Enter number of elements");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
  puts("Enter elements");
  scanf("%d",&x);
  insert(x);
}
preorder(root);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add your main function code. Better yet, don't split anything, unless your entire code is much much longer that what's already posted. Side note: your `preorder` function doesn't very if anything is `NULL` -> That definitely won't work.

Comment: Your traversal code checks if ptr1 is NULL but then it accesses ptr1->right and ptr1->left without checking first if they are not NULL.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you need the node, below which the new node needs to be inserted.
In your case when you are checking for the location where the new node needs to be inserted:

```
while(ptr1!=NULL)
  {
  if(x>ptr1->info)   //traversing to right if element is greater than  element present
    ptr1=ptr1->right;
  else
    ptr1=ptr1->left; //traversing to left if element is present than the the element
  }
```

You can store the previous pointer and then use that in the subsequent steps.

```
ptr1= root;
prev_ptr = NULL;
while(ptr1!=NULL)
      {
      prev_ptr = ptr;
      if(x>ptr1->info)   //traversing to right if element is greater than  element present  
        ptr1=ptr1->right;
      else
        ptr1=ptr1->left; //traversing to left if element is present than the the element
      }
```

Now use `prev_ptr` in the subsequent code that you have.

Comment: I am unable to figure out why I should do it

Comment: Say you have the tree with insertion sequence 4,3,7,6
And you are trying to insert 5. Then your ptr1 will traverse the tree in the following order 4->7->6, at 6, ptr1 is still not NULL and hence will continue into the while loop, and there the else condition will be executed and you will assign `ptr1 = ptr1->left` which will make `ptr1` `NULL` and hence exit the while loop. But you needed to make 5 the child of 6, for which you needed the pointer to the node 6. Thats the reason you need the `prev_ptr`

Comment: Sorry I posted it before completion, I have edited my earlier comment.